# What is matter really made up of?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, string-theory, universe, beyond-the-standard-model, matter

We know matter is made up atoms, and atoms are made up of **protons**, **neutrons**, and **electrons**. And we know that **protons** and **neutrons** are made up of smaller particles known as **quarks**. **Would probing deeper uncover particles even more fundamental ?**

**Atoms** are known to be **electrically neutral** **the positive charge of the protons is cancelled out by the negative charge of the electrons** but as to why this is so are known to be electrically neutral. The positive charge of the protons is cancelled out by the negative charge of the electrons,but **why this is so ?**

Comment: There is no end of asking 'why'! It is the way nature works. Goal of science is to understand how it works. See this [link]{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GT2zI8lVA}

Comment: This question does not have an established answer in physics. In the context of string theory (which is neither proven nor disproven so far), particles turn out to be vibrating strings of energy when you look at them at the Planck scale. But what is a string of energy made of? Nothing, it *is* the fundamental unit. But *why* is it so? As @SamapanBhadury says, the "why" leads to an endless loop in fundamental physics that nobody can solve.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st question mostly likely requires the construction and operation of the SSC, or CERN's next generation collider, ...and that may not be sufficient. So we all have to wait.

Regarding charge, we can't really answer 'why', rather, we can do a deeper dive on 'what':

If we stick to the 1st generation of particles (for brevity), leptons come in a doublet:

$$ \Big(\begin{array}{c}\nu\\e^-\end{array}\Big)$$

Likewise, the quarks come in a doublet:

$$ \Big(\begin{array}{c}u\\d\end{array}\Big)$$

These particles pretty much make up our macroscopic existence, including the Sun's core.

Note the charges from top to bottom all differs by -1 (in units of $|e|$), in both sectors:

$$ q_{\rm lepton} = \Big(\begin{array}{c}0\\-1\end{array}\Big)$$

$$ q_{\rm quark} = \Big(\begin{array}{c}+\frac 2 3\\-\frac 1 3\end{array}\Big)$$

That's important, and needs to be explained.

Moreover, we observe that quark bound states are color-singlets. With the $SU(3)$ structure of QCD, this leads to 3-quark baryons (e.g., the proton and the neutron).

And voilá: the "3" appears in the fractional charge we see in $q_{\rm quark}$, making the possible charges of basic baryons: -1, 0, 1, 2.

Isospin symmetry (aka flavor symmetry), and spin, lead to the lowest energy nucleon doublet:

$$ \Big(\begin{array}{c}p\\n\end{array}\Big)$$

having charges:

$$ q_{\rm nucleon} = \Big(\begin{array}{c}+1\\0\end{array}\Big)$$

and thus, the table of nuclides and Periodic table have their form.

There is a lot going on to make it all work out, and that may appear to all be happy coincidences. Most theorist prefer a deeper explanation than "happy coincidence", but this is the current state of the Standard Model.

Answer (score 1):

Despite careful analysis of millions (billions ?) of high energy particle collisions at the Large Hadron Collider and other particle accelerators, we see no indication that electrons or quarks have any internal structure. So, to the best of our knowledge, they are fundamental particles.

As to why atoms are neutral, they are not always so - you can have electrically charged ions, and at high temperatures atoms lose electrons and become a plasma. However, the electromagnetic force is a long range and powerful force, so it takes a lot of energy to separate positive and negative charges, and when they are separated they have a tendency to recombine with very energetic results - as in a lightning strike.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: we don't know.

The standard model stops at quarks and electrons because our best efforts cannot resolve these to anything smaller. Some speculative theories have proposed more fundamental constituents, such as preons or rishons, but have no experimental base to support them. If we could probe deeper, might we find something lurking down there? Who knows - but we certainly want to try!

But what is the nature of a fundamental particle? While it appears to experimentalists as an effectively dimensionless point, such singularities cannot occur in nature. The standard model, known as quantum field theory (QFT) treats it as a perturbation in the zero-point field which pervades all of spacetime. One widely-studied theory is that it is a vibrating "string" of energy trapped in a tiny convoluted multi-dimensional knot. There are other, less mainstream ideas, even particle realists who imagine that there is a primal solid blob down there, an actual old-style physical particle; however these particles must behave in such extraordinary and unconventional ways that it rather defeats the point of wanting real particles and few physicists take them seriously.

Coming back to the standard model with its quarks and electrons, why is it the way it is? We can only answer rather lamely that it is because it predicts the outcomes of experiments to an unparalleled level of sophistication, complexity and accuracy. What goes on "underneath" is a deep mystery.

We are sure that something does, because there are observations which the standard model cannot explain. For example it cannot explain gravity - for that we have to appeal to General Relativity, which is not wholly compatible with the standard model but also has stunning explanatory power. We imagine that gravity waves are somehow composed of "gravitons" but our best shot at a theory, loop quantum gravity, has serious problems. Nor can established theories explain galactic rotation and Universal expansion; we suspect that there is some kind of "dark matter" out there which interacts gravitationally but is transparent to light, and that there is some kind of "dark energy" driving the Universe apart, but we have frankly no idea what is going on in either department.

Indeed, fundamental physics is at something of an impasse these days. We are hoping that ever-more-powerful particle colliders will provide a route to new insights, as they always have before.